# Closure data cannot be accessed outside its scope

Tags: ios, swift, scope, closures

I'm making an asynchronous network request using Alamofire to an API.  Inside the closure, I am assigning the response's data to a particular variable (championRolesLibrary).  Now inside the closure, when I print the variable to see its contents ( item 1 ), it contains all the data I want it to have.  Outside the closure expression (item 2 ) when that same object is checked, and hasn't been modified in any way between 1 and 2, it no longer has any data and is empty.  Why is this?

```
Alamofire.request(championRolesUrl!).responseJSON { response in
    let result = response.result
        if result.isSuccess {
            if let data = result.value as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                for champion in data {
                    if let name = champion["name"] as? String {

                        if let roles = champion["roles"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
                            championRoles = []
                            for role in roles {
                                if let roleName = role["name"] as? String {
                                    championRoles.append(Role(roleName)!)
                                }
                            }
                            championRolesLibrary.append([name:championRoles])
                        }
                    }
                }
                print(championRolesLibrary) // 1
            }
        } else {
            print("Downloading Role Data Failed Because: \(result.error)")
        }
    }
}
print(championRolesLibrary) // 2
```

Comment: Put breakpoints on your two print statements and notice the order they are called.

Answer (score 1):

[Alamofire's documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) says:

> Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously. Asynchronous
>   programming may be a source of frustration to programmers unfamiliar
>   with the concept, but there are very good reasons for doing it this
>   way.

That means that when you do a request, you're doing it asynchronously, so when you print `championRolesLibrary` outside the closure, you're actually printing it before the data was returned by your request.

Answer (score 0):

Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used in your code. Closures in Swift are similar to blocks in C and Objective-C and to lambdas in other programming languages.

So, here your all code statement is executed before your Alamofire code is executing, after execution of every statement, Alamofire started its execution thats why you are not getting the value in out side the closure, because outsides statements​ has been executed already.